# Laptop Dedicated graphics or Shared Graphics

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Ok i currently have a laptop "Toshiba C650D-126".
And it works fine for me mostly but i recently started playing Euro Truck Simulator 2 on it and my laptop struggles even on the lowest settings but it is playable just occasionally i get a bit of lag.

I remembering hearing something about dedicated graphics cards being better than shared graphics cards or something so i am guessing that my current laptop has a shared graphics card.

So i'm guessing that i need to get a laptop with a dedicated graphics card but will that solve my problem completely or is there more to it than that????

Comment: Shared graphics make use of shared memory which is just using part of the RAM your machine uses. That's where the lag comes from. Dedicated, however, has it's own memory. Not really sure about the choices for laptops, however.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes - a dedicated card is more powerful.  However, CPU does indeed make a difference as does RAM.  So your minimum needs may be more than just "a dedicated graphics card" (i.e. to get a smooth experience - you may need a high end card with x cpu and y ram).

Comment: It's not that simple as "dedicated/integrated graphics card". Some GPUs are more powerful than other ones. Generally speaking, dedicated GPUs will be faster than integrated ones.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you should just go with a dedicated graphics card.  Most integrated GPU's will be lackluster in gaming performance and as stated by Alex will introduce additional lag through their use of shared memorty.

Aside from going with a discrete graphics card, how can you know how a card will perform?
Perform a google search for laptop graphics benchmarks and you can easily find sites which will rank various GPU's in addition to providing framerate data for each title.  I would start by finding a laptop that you are interested in and then checking to see what kind of performance it will get you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how can i check what performance a certain laptop will give me without actually using it. I mean i know there are various reviews and stuff but that's not normally for your exact laptop e.g i might find a review for a toshiba c650d in general but i not for an exact c650d-126?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't worry much about the specific laptop affecting performance with regard to gaming.  Why?  First of all the graphics card is the single most important factor in determining gaming performance and is almost always the limiting factor when it comes to laptops.  Second, most laptops that contain a discrete graphics chip are higher end and therefore contain more than powerful enough cpu's and amounts of memory. As long as you have 4gb + of ram and a recent CPU all you need to worry about is the GPU. While laptop reviews are often subjective GPU benchmarks are solid data.